# DRY up boilerplate in object/class default constructor

Tags: scala, refactoring, dry

I have something like this:

```
abstract class RunnerBase { def printErrorAndBreak = ... }

object Runner1 extends RunnerBase {
  breakable {
    doSomething
    if (cond1) printErrorAndBreak(...)
  }
}

object Runner2 extends RunnerBase {
  breakable {
    if (cond1) printErrorAndBreak(...)
    something else
  }
}
```

I'd like to move the `breakable { ... }` part into `RunnerBase` so that `Runner1` and `Runner2` looked like this instead:

```
object Runner1 extends RunnerBase {
  doSomething
  if (cond1) printErrorAndBreak(...)
}

object Runner2 extends RunnerBase {
  if (cond1) printErrorAndBreak(...)
  something else
}
```

Is this even possible? Or is my only way to wrap the subobject logic in, say, a `run` method?

---

**UPDATE:** Based on the accepted answer (and regardless of the comments), for the sake of robustness and simplicity, I've decided to go with this:

```
class RunnerBase { def run = breakable _ }
class Runner1 { run { doSmth; if (?) printErrorAndBreak } }
class Runner2 { run { doSmth; if (?) printErrorAndBreak } }
```

Not perfect because there's still the `run { ... }` repetition, but at least `breakable` and `break` are encapsulated in `RunnerBase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `DelayedInit`?

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks._

trait BreakInit extends DelayedInit {
  def delayedInit(body: => Unit) {
    breakable {body}
  }
}

class MyClass extends BreakInit {
  println("Hello World")
  break()
  println("Error - should not be reachable")
}

val a = new MyClass
```

In this case, we've created a trait `BreakInit` that inherits from `DelayedInit`, which overrides the `delayedInit` method to call the constructor within a `breakable` block. `MyClass`'s constructor is then rolled up into a function, and passed to the `delayedInit` method. As @som-snytt points out, the `DelayedInit` magic only affects class constructors, not trait constructors.

However, I'd advise a note of caution when using `DelayedInit`. It involves some reasonably deep compiler magic, and magic always comes with a price. Personally, I'd tend to prefer your original approach, as there's less magic involved.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to hear—yes, I'll stay with the original one, just doing `def run = breakable _` in the base class.

Comment: It's the other way around: trait init bodies are not delayedinited, but class bodies (including subclasses) are. Maybe it's the cargo-cultist in me talking, but this strikes me as a nice application of the DelayedInit magic; it has received a lot of hate mail and I think is scheduled for deprecation at some point (which is a reason not to go crazy with it).

Comment: @som-snytt I've sometimes had trouble getting subclasses of concrete`DelayedInit` classes to work with the `DelayedInit` magic. I always sort-of assumed that this was because the magic was single-use, but perhaps I was doing something else wrong. You'reright that I need to clarify the difference between class and trait behaviour.

Comment: Yep, I was definitely wrong about `DelayedInit` magic being single use. I just tried it with some subclasses of `BreakInit`, and it all works the way it's supposed to. I think the problems I'd had in the past were related to reckless use of mixins.